# SPI problem when install CAN controller driver

Tags: raspbian, kernel, driver, spi

I updated my raspi to 3.18.7+ last days and i also need new driver for my modules. I was waiting for PICAN board driver for pi and yesterday i uploaded it. Before uploaded;

ls -al /dev/spi*

crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.0

crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1

After;

ls -al /dev/spi*

crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1

Because of my project needs, i should use 2 channel on spi. one for PICAN board the other one MCP3008.

Who can give me an advice?

Comment: I guess you are using device tree.  Have you any entries in /boot/config.txt relating to dtoverlay?

Comment: there are no entries in /boot/config.txt relating to dtoverlay

Comment: How is the PICAN driver configured?  Is spidev0.1 the channel used by PICAN?

Comment: this is configuration command : modprobe spi-config devices=bus=0:cs=0:modalias=mcp2515:speed=10000000:gpioirq=25:pd=20:pds32-0=16000000:pdu32-4=0x2002:force_release

Comment: Do both devices exist before you modprobe PICAN?  Are you using device tree?  Do you have a dtparam=spi=on entry in /boot/config.txt?

Comment: I have a dtparam=spi=on entry in /boot/config.txt. I have no idea about device tree. First I set the PICAN cs:1 and i had shown same error.